# Iterate and Filter Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, elementtree

I have parsed a XML file into dictionary where I have

```
{'NY240': {'Enable_Notifications': 'Enabled',
  'Interface': 'LAN 1/3/2',
  'ID': '5058',
  'Location': 'NY240'
  'Speed': '0',
  'Validity': '1',
  'updateDate': '2018-02-05 14:02:57'},
'SF440': {'Enable_Notifications': 'Enabled',
  'Interface': 'WAN 1/2/2',
  'ID': '6353',
  'Location': 'SF440'
  'Speed': '1',
  'Validity': '1',
  'updateDate': '2018-02-08 16:02:57'},
...}
```

I get that with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

dict_s = {}
for child in root:
    for key in child:
        td={}
        for k in key:
            td.update({k.tag: k.text})
            if k.tag=='Location':
                dict_s.update({k.text:td})
        else:
            pass
```

I know I didn't paste XML file here but I think there is no need, it's simple XML file, anyone who is even a little better than me with python dictionary iterations can start from here. 
What I need is select just those keys (and values of them) where the value of inner key 'Interface' contain 'WAN' (not 'startswith'). In this case that will be a second one, SF440.

I have solved that this way, separatly:

```
new_td = {}
for key, value in dict_s.iteritems():
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        if k=='Interface' and 'WAN' in v:
            new_td.update({key: value})
```

But I'm looking for solution implemented in the top code block, not separated if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using python `dict comprehension`

```
dict_s = {'NY240': {'Enable_Notifications': 'Enabled',
  'Interface': 'LAN 1/3/2',
  'ID': '5058',
  'Location': 'NY240',
  'Speed': '0',
  'Validity': '1',
  'updateDate': '2018-02-05 14:02:57'},
'SF440': {'Enable_Notifications': 'Enabled',
  'Interface': 'WAN 1/2/2',
  'ID': '6353',
  'Location': 'SF440',
  'Speed': '1',
  'Validity': '1',
  'updateDate': '2018-02-08 16:02:57'},
}

print dict((key, value) for key, value in dict_s.items() if 'WAN' in value.get('Interface', None))
```

**Output:**

```
{'SF440': {'Validity': '1', 'Interface': 'WAN 1/2/2', 'Location': 'SF440', 'Enable_Notifications': 'Enabled', 'Speed': '1', 'ID': '6353', 'updateDate': '2018-02-08 16:02:57'}}
```